# how to fix this python hangman game?

Tags: python

I have coded this hangman game to test something, and it doesn't work properly.

Here is the code:

```
import  random
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase
secret_words = ["screen", "secret", "game", "hangman"]

def lowerChar(c):
    if 'A' <= c <= 'Z':
        return ascii_lowercase[ascii_uppercase.index(c)]
    else:
        return c

def get_guess():
    word = random.choice(secret_words)
    length = len(word)
    limit = 5
    count = 0
    display = "*" * length
    print(display, " Is the word")
    while count < 5:
        letter = input("Please Enter Your guess letter")
        for l in word:
            if letter.lower() == lowerChar(l):
                print("Right guess!")
                index = word.find(l)
                display = display[:index] + letter + display[index + 1: ]
                print(display)
                if not '*' in display:
                    print("You won!")
                    break
            else:
                count += 1
                print("You got it incorrect, you have: ", limit - count , " Additional    trials")

get_guess()
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific on what is not working? Do you get an error? Do you get the wrong results. SO is not for debugging your code, it's there to help you with specific problems you have.

Comment: One simplification is to use [string.lower()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/lower) rather than creating your own lowerChar function.

Comment: Please @MohamedabdElsattar read point 1 of off-topic in that link https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and try to improve your answer with some logs or more info.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing too much inside the block `for l in word`. You have to check, whether the character is contained in the word or not, outside this loop:

```
import random
secret_words = ["screen", "secret", "game", "hangman"]

def get_guess():
    word = random.choice(secret_words)
    count = 0
    display = "*" * len(word)
    print(display, " Is the word")
    while count < 5:
        letter = input("Please Enter Your guess letter")
        if letter.lower() not in word:
            count += 1
            print("You got it incorrect, you have: ", limit - count , " Additional    trials")
        else:
            print("Right guess!")
            new_display = ''
            for w, l in zip(word, display):
                if letter.lower() == w:
                    new_display += letter.lower()
                else:
                    new_display += l
            display = new_display
            print(display)
            if not '*' in display:
                print("You won!")
                break

get_guess()
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to Daniel's would be introducing a variable called `goodGuess` that allows you to check if the person has made a correct guess in the for loop, and then once you have exited the for loop, then checking if the player has made an incorrect guess, see below

```
import  random
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase
secret_words = ["screen", "secret", "game", "hangman"]

def lowerChar(c):
    if 'A' <= c <= 'Z':
        return ascii_lowercase[ascii_uppercase.index(c)]
    else:
        return c

def get_guess():
    word = random.choice(secret_words)
    length = len(word)
    limit = 5
    count = 0
    display = "*" * length
    print(display, " Is the word")
    while count < 5:
        letter = input("Please Enter Your guess letter")
        #as we do not yet know if this guess is good we set it to False until we do know
        goodGuess = False
        for l in word:
            if letter.lower() == lowerChar(l):
                #as the player has made a correct guess we set goodGuess to True
                goodGuess = True
                print("Right guess!")
                index = word.find(l)
                display = display[:index] + letter + display[index + 1: ]
                print(display)
                if not '*' in display:
                    print("You won!")
                    break
        #checking if the player has made a correct guess
        if not goodGuess:
            count += 1
            print("You got it incorrect, you have: ", limit - count , " Additional    trials")


get_guess()
```

Hope this helps.